# Combining two tables including rows not found in other table, substituting values in column

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables made from the following two queries:

```
SELECT t3.PatientID, SUM(t3.Fee) as total FROM     
(SELECT t1.TestID, t2.PatientID, t1.Fee FROM    
(SELECT Test.TestID, Test.Fee FROM MedicalTest AS Test) AS t1,    
(SELECT T.TestID, T.PatientID FROM Take AS T) AS t2    
WHERE t1.TestID = t2.TestID    
ORDER BY t2.PatientID) AS t3        
GROUP BY t3.PatientID    
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Which gives me a table of patient IDs and how much they have spent on tests, a portion of the table looks like this:

```
PATIENTID   TOTAL                            
----------- ---------------------------------
99642131                            550.00
99631255                            440.00
99665378                            430.00
99627956                            310.00
99657423                            280.00
99641125                            260.00
99630025                            230.00
99648682                            230.00
```

My other query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.PatientID FROM Diagnose AS D     
WHERE D.PhysicianID IN (    
SELECT P.PhysicianID FROM Physician AS P    
WHERE P.HName = 'Specific Hospital'    
AND P.DName = 'Intensive Care Unit');
```

Returns to me a list of Patient IDs who are under the care of a specific physician. A portion of the table:

```
PATIENTID  
-----------
99615376
99618797
99620783
99620882
99621221
```

I am trying to create a resultant table that contains the patient IDs from the second table as well as how much they have spent on medical tests from the first table. Some patients from the second table have not taken any tests in which case, I would like the table to simply give 0 for the total column, however, my attempt at combining the tables only gives me the patients who have taken tests:

```
SELECT t5.PatientID, t4.total FROM

(SELECT t3.PatientID, SUM(t3.Fee) as total FROM
(SELECT t1.TestID, t2.PatientID, t1.Fee FROM
(SELECT Test.TestID, Test.Fee FROM MedicalTest AS Test) AS t1,
(SELECT T.TestID, T.PatientID FROM Take AS T) AS t2
WHERE t1.TestID = t2.TestID
ORDER BY t2.PatientID) AS t3
GROUP BY t3.PatientID
ORDER BY total DESC) AS t4,

(SELECT DISTINCT D.PatientID FROM Diagnose AS D
WHERE D.PhysicianID IN (
SELECT P.PhysicianID FROM Physician AS P
WHERE P.HName = 'Specific Hospital'
AND P.DName = 'Intensive Care Unit')) AS t5

WHERE t5.PatientID = t4.PatientID;
```

Resultant table:

```
PATIENTID   TOTAL                            
----------- ---------------------------------
99642131                            550.00
99665378                            430.00
99627956                            310.00
```

How can I include the patients from table 2 that have not taken tests and enter 0 in their total column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.PatientID, COALESCE(total, '0') AS finalTotal
FROM Diagnose AS D
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT T.PatientID, SUM(M.Fee) AS total
FROM Take AS T, MedicalTest AS M
WHERE T.TestID = M.TestID
GROUP BY T.PatientID
          ) AS t1
ON t1.PatientID = D.PatientID
WHERE D.PhysicianID IN (
SELECT P.PhysicianID FROM Physician AS P
WHERE P.HName = 'Specific Hospital'
AND P.DName = 'Intensive Care Unit')
ORDER BY finalTotal DESC;
```

I use `COALESCE(total, '0')` with my `LEFT JOIN` to input 0 on the rows where no medical tests were done. This lead me to my desired output:

```
PATIENTID   FINALTOTAL                                
----------- ------------------------------------------
99642131                                     550.00
99665378                                     430.00
99627956                                     310.00
99615376                                          0
99618797                                          0
99620783                                          0
99620882                                          0
99621221                                          0
99642157                                          0
99655482                                          0
99664061                                          0
```